# UniFi Switch US 8-60w with a UniFi AP-AC-LR

Tags: switch, access-point, power-over-ethernet, ubiquiti

I've bought myself a UniFi AP-AC-LR and a UniFi Switch US 8-60w.
Are those two devices compatible to use power over ethernet cable to link them?

With kind regards

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

The access point UniFi AP-AC-LR uses 803.3/af mode A, and the switch US 8-60w supports it (according to their datasheets).

Ubiquiti publishes its compatibility matrix confirming this, here:
https://help.ubnt.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000263008--UniFi-Understanding-PoE-and-How-UniFi-Devices-are-Powered

I believe the switch also supports so-clled "Passive POE" -- which is really just power-over-CAT5 -- but this isn't a good idea for long cable runs, easy management, or standards compliance.